# OpenCart- File not found (404 error) on category pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, opencart

I have Opencart Version 1.5.6.4_rc, clean install.

I have created several product categories(with SEO friendly URLs), however, on clicking on category link it always shows the error - File not found(404 error).

I have checked there are no spaces between URL characters. The error is specific to category pages, information pages are fine.

My Htaccess looks like this.

```
# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled. 
# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.# For any support     issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com
Options +FollowSymlinks
# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes
# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)"> 
Order deny,allow 
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
#Fix Rewrite
Options -Multiviews
# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder  it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]  
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) #/index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} #!.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

# Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers 
### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.###
# If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the following settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.
# 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible register_globals is on. This may work to disable it:
#php_flag register_globals off
# 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:
#php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
# 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be overridden but you can try
#php_value upload_max_filesize 999M
# 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
#php_value post_max_size 999M
# 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
#php_value max_execution_time 36000
# 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
#php_value max_input_time 36000
# 7. disable open_basedir limitations
#php_admin_value open_basedir none
```

Comment: It woud be easier to help you if you copied your Htaccess here directly, instead of providing a link.

Comment: code embedded in post

Comment: I have a feeling that it my .htaccess file is not being read by the configuration. I am trying to fing the httpd.conf file to change override settings, but there is none on the server. Any ideas?

Comment: Just to be sure, did you rename the `.htaccess.txt` file to **`.htaccess`** only?

Comment: @shadyyx Yes, it is .htaccess only. I have been really stuck on this since last 24 hours, so I have tried everything multiple times now.

Comment: And did you turn on the SEO setting in administration - system - settings? It should be tab *Server* I think...

Comment: @shadyyx, yes, did that too

Comment: OK. Is it working for information pages, manufacturers and product detail pages? And not working only for categories? Or? Unfortunately, if this is not caused by any programmatic modification, I cannot help you more. Either you have installed some 3rd party extension or if it is completely clear install then I have no more ideas... Maybe one though - does your server support *RewriteEngine* (mod_rewrite) and is it enabled?

Comment: Server supports mod_rewrite. Its strange I just did a clean install today, and the 404 error still comes up on category pages. e.g. on mysite.com/shop where shop is the name of the category. There are no 3rd party extensions installed this time.